# How to deal with constants and Dependency Injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection

> **Update** My question is probably even simpler than explained below: Should I not use constants from other classes when using dependency injection?

I am converting a number of classes to have their dependencies injected, instead of defining them within the class. All good so far.

However, I have a number of constants, particularly related to an event dispatcher system, that I am not really sure what to do with.

For instance:

```
const STORAGE_SYSTEM_FLUSHED = MyDatabaseEvents::FLUSHED;

public function myFunctionForSO() {
    $this->ed->addListener(self::STORAGE_SYSTEM_FLUSHED, function() {
        // do some stuff
    });
}
```

`MyDatabaseEvents::FLUSHED` is nothing more than a string to identify the event, typically something along the lines of `"services.database.flush"`, but my approach causes  my classes to become dependent on classes such as MyDataBaseEvents, and more.

It feels a bit excessive to inject objects just for this string. How is this typically handled?

1) A global settings class injected?

2) A global event identfier class injected?

3) Configured by the calling class?

4) ...?

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe this is why subscribers exists, vs. specific listener's as I am using in the above example? That could solve my specific event dispatcher issue, but it still does not answer if constants cannot be used together with dependency injection.

Comment: The goal of dependency injection is not to remove dependencies entirely, the goal is to be able to easily 'mock' dependencies. E.g. in your example you can mock a `STORAGE_SYSTEM_FLUSHED` event to happen using a mocked storage system. This mocked object would share those constants. Another advantage is, say you switched from `MySQL` to `PostgreSQL`, you would only need to supply a `PostgreSQL` adapter or whatever to your `DI` system, this object would also share those constants. Nothing would change on the code shown here. (loosely coupled)

Comment: Why don't you just subscribe to `MyDatabaseEvents::FLUSHED`?

Answer (score -1):

If all you need is a string then pass only the string. Try to avoid making your class dependent on complex structures/objects If your constructor will get too complicated (too many arguments) you can try using something like a builder pattern to collect all arguments and create an object.

Comment: The initiating class would then need to know about the inner workings of the class using the string, thus probably violating some good programming rules?

Comment: Not really, you will always have classes responsible for constructing business objects. There will always be a class/function knowing more "hairy" details of construction. :) But it is the business logic (classes) you want to protect from construction details.

Answer (score -1):

You can use constant in DI

Consider this

```
class A{
  const XMLWALLSTATUS = 'TRUE';
  public function __construct()
  {
  }
}


class B{
  protected $avalue;
  public function __construct(A $avalue)
  {
    $this->avalue = $avalue
  }
  public function getFoo(){
    return $this->avalue::XMLWALLSTATUS;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)`